# Applying a patch that involve multiple modules

Tags: version-control

When I run apply patches to contributed modules, I download the patch, put it in the modules folder, and then execute `git apply patch patch_file_name` from that folder.

I never ran a patch for Drupal core, though, and I believe it's a bit different.

How can I apply a patch to Drupal core, which could involve multiple Drupal core modules?

Answer (score 3):

[Drush make](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/) is a method to maintain patched releases of contrib and core. It is the only organized, non-custom, method I know of for patch management. The makefile is self-documenting. By "self-documenting", I mean that the makefile contains a list of modules, their versions, and URLs of applied patches.

Create a makefile of an existing Drupal site with:

```
drush generate-makefile mysite.make
```

Note, as far as I know `drush generate-makefile` will not detect applied patches. The [example makefile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drush-ops/drush/master/examples/example.make.yml) demonstrates how to reference patches in your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `patch` command (read [here](https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply) for more). For eg. put the patch file in the folder where the file is stored for which the patch was written, then apply the patch.

```
patch < file.patch
```

**NOTE:** **for maintainability purposes, I follow these steps before and after the patch is successfully applied**.

- Make sure there is an issue in Drupal Core regarding the patch. If not then create one and upload the patch.
- Download the patch from the issue. If you use [patch naming guidelines](https://www.drupal.org/patch/submit#patch_naming) or [Dreditor](https://dreditor.org/) for patch name suggestion, then the patch will also have issue id. Also you can keep track of the issue to check if a better solution is available or the issue is closed(fixed).
- Make a folder in your Drupal installation inside **sites** folder or **root** folder and have a copy of the patch in there. This should be done so that if you update the Drupal Core, then your core changes will be removed and you can re-apply those patches using these copies.
- Delete the original patch from Drupal installation after the patch is used.

Comment: This answer explains how to apply patches but does not answer the question as posed.

Comment: I am sure Drush make will work but this answer is also valid for manual patch applying. *So, is there a one single way to run Drupal core patches and how it should be done without damaging anything?* Patch applying is same for drupal core patches.

Comment: Generally you will need to do: patch -p1 < patch-file-name.patch

Comment: Worth noting that almost always, patches will be written to be applied from the root of the site, the same as the root of the module for a module patch. Consider core to be one huge module.